# XmlSlurper Append node with namespace

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I am trying to append node to my request using `xmlslurper`

```
Service.appendNode{
  ifx:DepAcctId{
    if (acctId!="<!-->"){ifx:AcctId("123")}
  }
}
```

This results in

```
<DepAcctId>
  <AcctId>123</AcctId>
</DepAcctId>
```

I want it to append the namespace, like

```
<if:DepAcctId>
  <ifx:AcctId>123</ifx:AcctId>
</ifx:DepAcctId>
```

Please help.

This is the exact code that I am using.

```
holderRequest = tsuite.getTestCaseAt(2).getTestStepByName(tcName).testRequest.getRequestContent()
request = new XmlSlurper(true,true).parseText(holderRequest).declareNamespace(v2:'http://www.fnf.com/xes/services/acct/acctinq/v2_1',
    ifx:"http://www.ifxforum.org/IFX_150",soapenv:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", xes:"http://www.fnf.com/xes")
Service = request.'soapenv:Body'.'v2:AcctInqRq'
Service.appendNode {
    ifx:DepAcctId {
        if (acctId!="<!-->"){ifx:AcctId(acctId)}
        if (acctType!="<!-->"){ifx:AcctType(acctType)}
        if (BankInfo!="<!-->"){ifx:BankInfo(BankInfo)}
    }
}
xmlBuilder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
writer = xmlBuilder.bind {
    mkp.declareNamespace(soapenv:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",ifx:"http://www.ifxforum.org/IFX_150",
        v2:"http://www.fnf.com/xes/services/acct/acctinq/v2_1",xes:"http://www.fnf.com/xes")
    mkp.yield request
}
holderRequest = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(XmlUtil.serialize(new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {mkp.yield request}))
log.info holderRequest.getXml()
tsuite.getTestCaseAt(2).getTestStepByName(tcName).getProperty("request").setValue(holderRequest.getXml())
```

The tags are getting added but without the `ifx` namespace prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Service.appendNode{
  'ifx:DepAcctId'{
    if (acctId!="<!-->"){'ifx:AcctId'("123")}
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add runnable code and the actual exception to your question?

Comment: @RamyaaSeetharaman so that means `request.'soapenv:Body'.'v2:AcctInqRq'` is returning `null`...  My crystal ball is broken, so it's hard to guess what your xml is to see what the answer might be...

Comment: Tim, is there any other way that I could add nodes to my xml with namespace prefix? Also I'm doubtful that request.'soapenv:Body'.'v2:AcctInqRq' is returning null because my nodes are getting added,just the prefix is not.